# Deployment vs POD - change

Tags: kubernetes

I was wondering what would happen in this scenario or if it's even possible:

Kubernetes cluster -
If the deployment has a container restartPolicy of: Always

but on the POD level you specify a restartPolicy of: Never

Which will Kubernetes do?

Comment: The deployment creates the pod. IIRC, there is no way to have the restart policy between a pod and its deployment differ. If it would differ, the deployment would redeploy the pod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Turing85 commented, in the normal use case a Deployment and its Pod cannot have different `restartPolicy`s, as the Deployment creates the Pods. If you try to alter the Pods `restartPolicy` manually after it is created (e.g. with `kubectl edit pod <pod-name>`) you will get an error, as this property cannot be changed after creation. However, we can trick a Deployment or more specifically the underlying ReplicaSet into accepting a manually created Pod. ReplicaSets in Kubernetes know which Pods are theirs through the use of labels. If you inspect the ReplicaSet belonging to your Deployment, you will see a label selector, that shows you which labels need to be present for the ReplicaSet to consider the Pod part of the ReplicaSet.

So if you want to manually create a Pod that is later managed by the ReplicaSet, you first create a Pod with the desired `restartPolicy`. After this Pod has started and is ready you delete an existing Pod of the ReplicaSet and update the labels of your pod to contain the correct labels. Now there is a Pod in the ReplicaSet with a different `restartPolicy`.

This is really hacky and actually depends on the timing of deletion and update of the labels, because as soon as you delete a Pod in the ReplicaSet it will try to create a new one. You essentially have to be faster with the label change than the ReplicaSet is with the creation of a new Pod.